# How do I correctly implement a Snackbar, Coordinator Layout and a bottom|right FAB?

Tags: android, android-coordinatorlayout, floating-action-button, android-snackbar

I'm currently using the Design Support Library. I've tried implementing the Snackbar with my CoordinatorLayout wraping the entire layout. When the Snackbar is to be displayed, it raises the FAB. But it makes no effort to come down and thereby stays above the translated distance.

It however, does come down when I dismiss the Snackbar by swiping it. So the CoordinatorLayout is aware of the FAB wrapped inside.

.xml

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/coordinator_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relative_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/primary"
            android:elevation="4dp"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

        <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
            android:id="@+id/ad_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/toolbar"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            ads:adSize="BANNER"
            ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id" />

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@id/ad_view">

            <include layout="@layout/card_view" />

        </ScrollView>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/btn_generate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|right|end"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_refresh_white_24dp"
        app:elevation="6dp"
        app:fabSize="normal"
        app:pressedTranslationZ="12dp" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

.java

```
Snackbar.make(mCoordinatorLayout, R.string.copied_to_clipboard,
                Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Answer (score 5):

If you want to show the `Snackbar` such that while it showed up, the `CoordinatorLayout` will be adjusted, then try the code below

```
findViewById(R.id.btn_generate).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View view) {
        Snackbar.make(view, "Hello Snackbar", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      }
});
```

Comment: No luck. The case remains the same.

Comment: @AchillesRasquinha I think this will help https://lab.getbase.com/introduction-to-coordinator-layout-on-android/

Comment: Yes. I'd checked 'em all. Including the documentation. But no luck.

Comment: make SURE to add the ```.show()``` I forget this SO MANY times.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the code below, it should work fine. This is how I implement my snackbar in all of my projects and it has never failed me. Study carefully; merry coding ;-) !

```
Snackbar.make(findViewById(android.R.id.content),"Your text",Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Remember, never forget your `show()` method, your snackbar is useless without it.

**EDIT:**

If you're using databinding or viewbinding, you can attach/anchor your SnackBar to any view within your layout by doing something like this:

```
Snackbar.make(binding.button, message, Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
```

Kindly note that you can still use this approach even if you're not using data/view binding. Just pass the view as the first argument.

Comment: The catch is to use android.R.id.content rather than some non-existent ID. Saves you a lot of stress and keeps your sanity.

Comment: Please help. I do not want to write any layout code for snacker. So thought of using the above code. But it is crashing the app. android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #39 in com.domain.appname:layout/design_layout_snackbar_include: Binary XML file line #39 in com.domain.appname:layout/design_layout_snackbar_include: Error inflating class <unknown>
                                                                Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #39 in com.domain.appname:layout/design_layout_snackbar_include: Error inflating class <unknown>

Comment: I've edited my answer, @niravdinmali. Let me know if the updated answer is helpful.